# pass oauth2 client-id and client-secret from spring boot bean to yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, yaml

I want to pass the oauth2 client-id and client-secret from spring boot bean to yaml, instead of directly hardcoding the values in yaml file. My client-id and client-secret are securely retrieved from Harshicorp Vault and i want to pass them on to the yaml securely. How do i do that ? I tried something like below

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.security.oauth2.registration.custom-client")
@Slf4j
public class SSOConfig {


    private String client_id;

    private String client_secret;

    public void setClient_secret(String client_secret) {
        this.client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }

    public String getClient_secret() {
        return client_secret;
    }

    public void setClient_id(String client_id) {
        this.client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }

    public String getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }
```

yaml

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-client:
            client-id: (this line is removed completely)
            client-secret: (this line is removed completely)
            scope: ["openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone", "groups"]
            provider: custom-provider
            state: xoxoxo
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
```

I removed the client-id and client-secret from yaml after adding this piece of code but still error throws like client-id cannot be empty

Comment: you don't want the oauth configuration to pick properties from a file, instead you want to hardcode through the code, is that what you want to do? If yes, well you can override the default configuration or define clientbean that consists the client_id and secret.

Comment: yes Amit, i dont want to pick client-id and client-secret properties from yaml file, i want them to be picked up from the bean (code). how to do that ? can you please point me in right direction ?

Comment: I will post a code with repo on github

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for posting late. I had to go through spring docs and found that with latest spring security oauth2, the default implementation will auto configure everything but in case you want to override the default configuration, In case your case you want to provide the client details by your own, you can override it by creating a `@Bean` named `ClientRegistrationRepository` this way,

```
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
            .clientId("google-client-id")
            .clientSecret("google-client-secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
            .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
            .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
            .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
            .clientName("Google")
            .build();
    }
```

---

Learn more about overriding autoconfiguration. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.2/reference/html5/#oauth2login-override-boot-autoconfig)